# Cassandra query to get the last row of a table

Tags: java, cassandra-2.0

Can anyone help me get the last record of a table in cassandra. I want get the last row based on a primary key. I tried using order by for the key still it shows error as either IN or EQ required for using order by. When I added a IN clause, it shows error. Please explain me how to solve this with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't :)

Data is only "ordered" inside of a partition via the clustering keys. You can do order by queries on a clusterin columns assuming that the partition key and all prior clustering keys have an exact match. In other words, if you have a PK of (a,b,c) then you can do where a='asd' and b='cds' and then do range queries on c.

You can specify clusterin order on a partition, so for the latest, if you have clustering as timestamp desc, then simply selecting first will automatically give you "last". For example:

```
create table timeseries (
  event_type text,
  insertion_time timestamp,
  event blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_type, insertion_time)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (insertion_time DESC);
```

Note, you'll need to specify  the parition key (event_type) and the retrieved row will be the "latest" in that partition.

Think however, what it means to be "latest" in a distributed system. Any notion of "latest" is likely to be out of date depending on your use case. This may or may not be acceptable.

If you're looking for "latest" via an arbitrary column that is not a desc clustering key, then I would recommend using Spark to do a fast "map reduce" like computation.